# Does Angular Require RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Simple enough - does core Angular require RxJS if I am not using any observables or http calls?

In the future, how do I check myself if Angular really requires X for a Hello World app?

Comment: WebPack only adds JavaScript libraries that have been imported into your project. Requiring a dependencies to be install via `npm` doesn't mean that it will end up in your bundles when you run the application, but Angular does need RxJs. Which operators are compiled into your bundles depends upon which you use or are used by Angular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. RxJS is a peer dependency of `@angular/core`, as you can see in its [package.json file](https://github.com/angular/core-builds/blob/master/package.json#L18-L21):